# Required VLAN overlapping allowed?

Tags: cisco, vlan, subnet, cisco-commands, interface

I configured the switch for two VLANs, as below:

```
Projects-3560-(config)#int vlan11

Projects-3560-(config-if)#ip address 10.110.1.1 255.255.255.0

Projects-3560-(config)#int vlan10

Projects-3560-(config-if)#ip address 10.110.0.1 255.255.0.0
% 10.110.0.0 overlaps with Vlan11
```

I am getting the above error.

I want a specific IP address to be used in vlan10, which is `10.110.0.180`. Also, I should not change the vlan11 gateway and subnet mask, as it is used by other applications.

Can any  one help?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have networks with overlapping addresses. A router needing to route between the two networks could not determine which network to use. Routing must be deterministic.

If you need a host with an address of `10.110.0.180` on VLAN 10, then you could use the `10.110.0.0/24` network for VLAN 10 instead of the `10.110.0.0/16` network. Change the mask on VLAN 10 to `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the following as per your suggestion: Projects-3560-(config-if)#ip address 10.110.0.0 255.255.255.0
Bad mask /24 for address 10.110.0.0    i got the the above error

Comment: Did changing the mask work?

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the following as per your suggestion:
Projects-3560-(config-if)#ip address 10.110.0.0 255.255.255.0 
Bad mask /24 for address 10.110.0.0
i got the the above error

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to include the whole switch configuration.

Comment: is there any error in the command i have given? can you  Please suggest the command? i am not a network administrator. i am a developer.

Comment: You may have some configuration in your switch that is causing the problem. Just edit your question to include the whole switch configuration. We can look to see if there is a problem, and suggest the proper solution.

Comment: it worked by giving the following command: ip address 10.110.0.1 255.255.255.128

Comment: That is because you have another VLAN or something set with the other part of the `/24` (`10.110.0.128/25`), which is why I wanted to the the whole configuration. Your problem now is that the `10.110.0.180` address doesn't fall into the `10.110.0.0/25` range. If you don't want to cooperate and give us what we need to help you (the whole switch configuration) we simply cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the interface configuration mode wants a real IP address with the subnet mask. Something like

Projects-3560-(config-if)#ip address 10.110.0.**1** 255.255.**255**.0

You can't assign a network subnet to an interface

Josh